# given a concave function $f(x)$, why $f(x)- xf'(x)>0$?

Tags: functions

Given a concave function $f(x)$ defined for $x \ge 0$, I am trying to understand whether $g(x) = f(x)- x f'(x)$ should be positive or not.

From what I am reading it seems that it should be positive, but I cannot understand why. Any help?

Comment: Concavity is not affected by adding constants to $f$. Positivity of $f - xf'$ is. So no, the claimed inequality is false.

Comment: In the case of concave functions, is there any specific relation between $f$ and $xf'$ that I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ has the second derivative and it is  concave for $x\geq 0$.

If $f(0)>0$ then the property holds. Infact $g(0)=f(0)>0$ and for $x>0$, $g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(x)-xf''(x)=-xf''(x)\geq 0$. Hence $g$ is increasing and always positive for $x\geq 0$.

Otherwise you have counterexamples: for any concave function $h(x)$ take $f(x)=h(x)-h(0)-1$ then $f$ is still concave and $g(0)=-1<0$.

Comment: Is the reverse true? I.e does $f(x)>xf’(x)$ imply that $f$ is concave (I think if we take the derivative of both sides and simplify we find that $f’’(x)<0 $ which implies $f$ is strictly concave?)

Comment: @user106860 $f>g$ does not imply that $f'>g'$

Answer (score 3):

**COUNTEREXAMPLE**

$$f(x)=-x^2-1 \Rightarrow g(x)=x^2-1$$

$g(x)$ is not always positive nor is it always negative.

So your inequality is false.

Answer (score 0):

The first order Taylor approximation of $f(a)$ is $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$. Now, this approximation clearly bounds it above, since $f(a)-af'(a)+f'(a)x$ is the tangent to $f(a)$, a concave function. Taking this together, we arrive in:

$$f(a) \le f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$$
$$f(0) \le f(a)-af'(a) $$

Now, we can't assume that $f(0)$ would be  $0$ or greater, so your inequality is not always true.