# Does $f(x)>xf'(x)$ for all $x$ imply that $f$ is concave?

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

where $f(x):[c,\infty]\to [0,A]$ is increasing, positive, $c>0$, and $f(c)=0$ (or, if it makes a difference, assume $f(c)>0$, but if we need this please state it). ($A$ is some positive constant. I.e. $f$ is bounded. The point of $c$ is to get $0$ out of the domain, to deal with what `GReyes` mentioned in a comment)

This is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1889865/344247), but with the direction reversed.

Edit: and as a potential clarification, by "for all $x$" (in the title), I mean for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: You actually cannot have $f(0)=0$ since your condition will then read $0>0$ which is false. Is it possibly $f(x)\ge xf'(x)$?

Comment: In the earlier question the domain is $[0,\infty)$. Are you sure you want to change it to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I want to domain to be $[c,\infty]$, with $c>0$. I will specify this (I am not doing $[0,\infty]$  because of `Greyes` comment)

Answer (score 0):

We still can't have $f(c)=0$ for the same reason as in the comment: there's no way for $f(c)>cf'(c)$, and by continuity it would continue to fail for values just to the right of $x=c$.

In any case, there's no reason that concavity should hold, and here's how to construct a counterexample: start with a function satisfying the hypotheses, say $f(x)=2-1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$. Then modify it by adding a small function with a small derivative but a very large second derivative near a point, say
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if } 1\le x\le 55, \\
10(x-55)^2, &\text{if } 55\le x\le 55.01, \\
10(55.02-x)^2, &\text{if } 55.01\le x\le 55.02, \\
0, &\text{if } x\ge 55.02.
\end{cases}
$$
(Note that $g(x)\ge0$ and $|g'(x)|\le \frac15$, while $g''(x)$ can be as large as $20$.) Then $f(x)+g(x)$ still satisfies the hypotheses but is no longer concave.

Comment: What is the reason for having the derivative of $g$ go negative from $55.01$ to $55.02$? Doesn't this make $f(x)+g(x)$ decreasing from 55.01 to 55.02? (which violates $f(x)+g(x)$ being increasing?)

Comment: I wanted $g(x)$ to be $0$ for large $x$. You're right, but just tweak the constants and $f'(x)$ will be more positive than $g'(x)$ is negative there.

Comment: Ah, and the $10(55.02-x)^2$ allows the first derivative to change continuously (i,e, go to zero without a kink). Does that sound right?

Comment: That is correct!